# Eclipse unable to recognize m2 repo from host os

Tags: eclipse, maven, virtualbox

I created a virtual box using oracle virtualbox. Now on host os I downloaded the java maven project in the folder "project" .  Then this folder is shared between the host & virtualbox.  On virtual box, I created the eclispe workspace and imported the maven project from the shared folder.  I also shared the .m2 folder between the host and virtualbox and modified the M2_REPO path in eclipse to point it to .m2 from shared folder. But still eclipse show errors and doesn't compile.

Thanks

Comment: What errors? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Compilation errors.

Comment: You should share the error stack and also the configuration you did to change the M2 path to help us understand the exact issue better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the eclipse that was installed did had m2e plugin. After installing it was able to compile.